# JavaScript array contains elements but length returns 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I am creating an Array of days between 2 given dates, the keys should be formatted as DD/MM/YYYY and the values should be numbers (prices set for each date)

It seems to work because the Array contains the values I give it (via a date picker) but I can not loop through this Array, probably because it's length returns 0 even though it contains elements

Here is a screenshot of the console log statement

[image]

Here is the code that creates the Array

```
  var arrayOfDatesBetween = new Array();
  // daysBetween = integer representing the count of days between the chosen dates
  for (let i = 0; i < daysBetween; i++) {
    // just add one day on each iteration but keep count of the first
    let q = i === 0 ? i : 1;
    let _date = _dateIn.setDate(_dateIn.getDate()+q);
    // lcsgDate() formats the date as I need it: DD/MM/YYYY
    let __date = lcsgDate(_date);
    // getDatePrice() gets the price for the given date by searching into another Array of date:price
    arrayOfDatesBetween[__date] = getDatePrice(__date);
  }
  // result
  console.log(arrayOfDatesBetween);
```

Comment: `"10/07/2018"` is not an integer index.

Comment: If it has keys, it's not an array; an array has indices.

Comment: consider changing format to `[{'date':'09/07/2018','price':'44'},{'date':'09/11/2018','price':'45'}]`, which will make it easier to traverse

Comment: @melpomene so I can do it with an object? Objects have keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that changing `arrayOfDatesBetween` from Array to Object solved the issue and I can now have non-integers as keys, just as I needed, Thanks for commenting and pointing me to the right direction

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Post comments as comments and additional information as edits to the question.

Comment: This is intentionally an answer because it solved the issue and I am waiting the 2 days imposed by stackoverflow before I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3]
arr['someCustomDate'] = 'someCustomData'


console.log(arr) // [1,2,3]
console.log(arr['someCustomDate'])
```

You code is essentially same as above, you're defining the property of an array instead of pushing them into the array.

To handle in your situation, you have two options:

**1:** for every element of your array, create an object and push them into your array like below:

```
 var arrayOfDatesBetween = new Array();
 // daysBetween = integer representing the count of days between the chosen dates
 for (let i = 0; i < daysBetween; i++) {
 // just add one day on each iteration but keep count of the first
   let q = i === 0 ? i : 1;
   let _date = _dateIn.setDate(_dateIn.getDate()+q);
   // lcsgDate() formats the date as I need it: DD/MM/YYYY
   let __date = lcsgDate(_date);
   // getDatePrice() gets the price for the given date by searching into another Array of date:price

   //HERE <=======
   let newObjectElement = { date: __date, price: getDatePrice(__date)};
   //arrayOfDatesBetween[__date] = getDatePrice(__date);
   arrayOfDatesBetween.push(newObjectElement);
}
// result
console.log(arrayOfDatesBetween);
```

**2:** Remain your code, but using `Object.keys` to loop over `__date`.

Highly recommended to pick option 1 because thats the sole reason to use `Array` instead of pushing element as a key